# Get 3 unique items from an Array in Swift - each with unique values

Tags: arrays, swift, unique

I have an array of key/value pairs and want to retrieve a random number of items. However I require the values to be distinct and to not return the same item multiple times.

For example:

```
Apple     1
Banana    1
Orange    2
Kiwi      2
Pear      3
Pineapple 4
```

I might want to retrieve 3 unique items. I.e. all 3 have different values and the same item is not return twice.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: amended answer to deal with case where there are not 3 different values. In which case fewer are returned.

Using Swift 2 with Xcode 7 beta 6

Since I am unclear how the array is declared here are 2 different possible versions. The idea is the same in each case.

```
// in this version the array is declared as follows:
let myArray01 = [["Apple",1], ["Banana", 2], ["Orange", 2], ["Kiwi",2], ["Pear",3],["Pineapple",4]]

var myArrayCopy01 = myArray01 // a mutable copy of the array from which items can be safely removed
var counter01:UInt32 = 5 // the number of items in the array
var myResult01 = [Array<NSObject>]()
var interimSelection01: [NSObject]

while myResult01.count < 3 && counter01 > 0 { // the number of randomly selected items we want
    interimSelection01 = myArrayCopy01.removeAtIndex(Int(arc4random_uniform(counter01--))) // random selection is removed from mutable copy & counter01--
    if !(myResult01.map{$0[1]}).contains(interimSelection01[1]) {
        myResult01.append(interimSelection01) // if we don't already have 1 with that value
    }
}

print(myResult01)
```

---

```
// in this version the pair is an array of tuples:
let myArray02: [(fruit: String, value: Int)]  = [("Apple",1), ("Banana", 2), ("Orange", 2), ("Kiwi",2), ("Pear",3),("Pineapple",4)]

var myArrayCopy02 = myArray02 // a mutable copy of the array from which items can be safely removed
var counter02:UInt32 = 5 // the number of items in the array
var myResult02 = [(fruit: String, value: Int)]()
var interimSelection02: (fruit: String, value: Int)

while myResult02.count < 3 && counter02 > 0 { // the number of randomly selected items we want
    interimSelection02 =  myArrayCopy02.removeAtIndex(Int(arc4random_uniform(counter02--))) // random selection is removed from mutable copy & counter02--
    if !(myResult02.map({$0.value}).contains(interimSelection02.value)) {
        myResult02.append(interimSelection02) // if we don't already have 1 with that value
    }
}

print(myResult02)
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Hold on! I found out that this algorithm is slightly biased! Only use it if you don't really care about this.

Using part of the Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm, I made an extension on `CollectionType` to return an `Array` of `n` randomly selected elements from the collection. Works with any type of collection (see examples). Complexity is `O(n)`. If `n` is greater than the number of elements in the collection, it doesn't crash but returns all elements at random. Tested in Swift 2.0 beta 6:

```
import Darwin

func randomUpTo(n: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(n)))
}

extension CollectionType {
    func chooseRandom(n : Int = Int.max) -> [Generator.Element] {
        var values = Array(self)
        for index in values.indices.dropFirst().reverse().prefix(n) {
            swap(&values[randomUpTo(index)], &values[index])
        }
        return Array(values.suffix(n))
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
(0...20).chooseRandom(10)    // [16, 20, 2, 7, 11, 13, 18, 9, 17, 4]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11].chooseRandom()    // [9, 11, 3, 5, 7, 1]

[
    ("Apple"    , 1),
    ("Banana"   , 1),
    ("Orange"   , 2),
    ("Kiwi"     , 2),
    ("Pear"     , 3),
    ("Pineapple", 4)
].chooseRandom(3)    // [("Apple", 1), ("Pineapple", 4), ("Kiwi", 2)]
```

EDIT: Complexity is indeed `O(n)`, however performance can be bad if the collection contains a lot of elements as they are copied. I am working on a lazy version right now that fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are hashable, you can use a Set.

```
import Foundation

extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Hashable, Index == Int {
  func sample(n: Int) -> Set<Generator.Element> {
    var result = Set<Generator.Element>()
    while result.count < n {
      let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
      result.insert(self[i])
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

If your elements are not hashable, you can use the indices to ensure uniqueness:

```
extension CollectionType where Index == Int {
  func sample(n: Int) -> [Generator.Element] {
    var result = Set<Int>()
    let c = UInt32(count)
    while result.count < n {
      result.insert(Int(arc4random_uniform(c)))
    }
    return result.map { i in self[i] }
  }
}
```

The second method here assumes that the collection you're sampling from doesn't contain duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Data structure for this.

```
Map<String, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    List<Integer> valueList = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entryMap : map.entrySet()) {
        if (!valueList.contains(entryMap.getValue())
                && valueList.size() < 3) {
            valueList.add(entryMap.getValue());
            newMap.put(entryMap.getKey(), entryMap.getValue());
        }

    }
    System.out.println(newMap);
```